# Modgrammar defining nested strings in python

Tags: python, string, parsing, modgrammar

I need to define Strings for a custom language parser. I am using modgrammar to define this language parser. This language (sqf) has a datatype String which allows for nesting.

A string is denoted by the standard double quotes ("), a string within a string is denoted by two sets of double quotes example.

`"this is a string ""this is a string within a string"""`

As far as i am aware there is no limit as to the levels of nesting.

So far i have tried the following to parse strings:

```
from modgrammar import *
class String (Grammar):
    grammar =  (
        (L("\""), ANY_EXCEPT("\""), (L("\"")),
           (
           OPTIONAL((L("\""),
                REF("String"),
                (L("\""))
           )
    )
String.grammar_resolve_refs()
```

And

```
class String (Grammar):
    grammar =  (
        (L("\""),
         ANY_EXCEPT("\""),
        (L("\"")
    )

class StringNested (Grammar):
    grammar = (String,OPTIONAL((L("\""),REF("StringNested"),(L("\""))

    )
```

and:

```
 class StringBase (Grammar):
     grammar_greedy = True
     grammar = (REPEAT(WORD("A-Za-z0-9")))
 class String (Grammar):
    # grammar =(OR(
    #     OR((StringBase,LITERAL('"'),StringBase, LITERAL('"')), (LITERAL('"'),StringBase,LITERAL('"'),StringBase) ),
     #    StringBase,
     # ))
     grammar = L('"'),OPTIONAL(L('"'),StringBase,L('"')),    OPTIONAL(LITERAL('"'),L('"'),REF("String"), LITERAL('"'),L('"')), (StringBase),L('"')
```

neither of these seem to be working.

edit: using python 3.4 and modgrammar 0.10
edit 2: NOTE:
I have found that while mod grammar is powerful and good at what it does it may not be the right solution my problem, I found that a hand coded linear parsing was much more efficient at parsing data in this instance data provided is already programmic output and therefor unlikely to contain errors in a way that would require such extensive testing as modgrammar allows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found a solution that seems to work (pending extensive testing).

The answer can be found here:

[Google Groups: Parsing Escaped Characters](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/modgrammar/VyDnXfqbBsA/GbJvSBPwDeAJ)

posted by Dan S:

> Dan S
>   08/09/2012
>   Found one way:
>       grammar = ('"', ZERO_OR_MORE(WORD('^"') | WORD('^\', '"', count=2)), '"')